# For loop not stopping at the correct value in list

Tags: python, list, loops, csv

This function retrieves all the information in a csv file and copies it into a list called `lines`. It should then search through the database (which contains account information), and find the right username and password.

However, currently my program fails to find the `username` and `password` in `lines`, and instead prints the record at the end of the database. Any ideas why this happens?

```
def Changer(user_information, weight):
    r = csv.reader(open('AccountsTest.csv'))
    username = user_information[0][0]
    password = user_information[0][1]
    lines = list(r)
    for n, line in enumerate(lines):
        if [username, password] == list(line):
            break
    print (lines[n])
```

When i `print username and password`, 'dom' gets outputted (which is correct). However, when i `print (lines[n])`, the final record inside the CSV file gets outputted, when i want it to output the 'dom' record.

The structure of my CSV file is as follows:

```
username, password, weight, goal, workout
```

In this example, only the first two (`username` and `password`) are important

The record from the CSV file which i am trying to copy looks like this

```
[['dom', 'dom', '70', 'strong'],[['Bench Press', 'Chest Press Machine', 'Incline Chest Press Machine', 'Incline Bench Press'],['test', 'test']]]
```

Comment: Please add some sample input and output data to your question.

Comment: That plural in `list(lines)` looks suspicious...

Comment: The simplest answer is the condition `if [username, password] == list(lines):` was never met.  Start looking from there.

Comment: `if [username, password] == list(lines):` should be `list(line)`

Comment: Should `if [username, password] == list(lines)` be `if [username, password] == line`?

Comment: Apologies, I have it as list(line). I made a mistake in typing the code back up. I have edited it again to represent what my code actually looks like

Comment: Can you add example file to check your code on some real data?

Comment: You are comparing a list of two elements, username and password, to a list of four elements, sername, password, goal, weight, workout.  Try `if [username, password] == line[:2]` to slice out username and password from list.

Comment: You are passing line with 4 elements while checking for the array with 2 elements.

Comment: that works! that solves it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing a list of two elements `[username, password]` to a list of five elements `[username, password, goal, weight, workout]`. Try

```
if [username, password] == line[:2]
```

to slice out username and password from list

Answer (score 0):

Seems like list(line) never equals [username,password].
Can't find anything else suspicious about your code.

Few things that I think you should check:

1. Make sure your lists are at the same length as you meant.
2. Make sure that your 'DB' actually written in the same order as you checked [username, password].
3. Make sure user information data is correct.

GL

Comment: User information is pulled from the database, so it should be exactly the same.

Comment: I made some more edits to the question. Please have another look and see if the edits are more helpful :D